# Autoplay/pause a video when hovering

Tags: jquery, video, hover, pause

I have a map of a city with dots spread out, which will show videos when hovering the dots but i can´t discover how to make it autoplay and then stop when the mouse leaves.

Here is a working snippet with the example: (here's the [JSFiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/v3mdopmy/1/))

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#video1').css("display", "none"); //Hide video initially
  $('#video-wrapper1').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#video1').css("display", "block", "position", "absolute",
      "top", "100px"); //Show video on hover
  });
  $('#video-wrapper1').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#video1').css("display", "none");
  });

$("#video1").mouseenter(function(){
$(this).attr("src",$(this).attr("src") + "?autoplay=1");
});

$("#video1").mouseleave(function(){
var src= $(this).attr("src");
var arr_str = src.split("?");
$(this).attr("src",arr_str[0]);
});    

});
```

```css
.bg {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  img.bg {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;
  }
}
#video-wrapper1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 700px;
  top: 100px;
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  z-index: 99999;
  background: #0073ff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition-property: width, height;
  transition-duration: .2s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
#video-wrapper1:hover {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://s32.postimg.org/t78dw1h1h/Fundo.png" class="bg" alt="Lisboa">
<a href="index.html">
  <img src="http://s32.postimg.org/bdlm2uvt1/Logo.png" alt="" />
</a>
<div id="video-wrapper1">
  <iframe id="video1" width="200" height="169" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Inufy4FdnRk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Sorry that the blue dot isn't in place, I need to find a way to make it stick in the correct coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You can play any youtube video by placing `?autoplay=1` in the end . For eg.

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/Inufy4FdnRk?autoplay=1
```

this will automatically play your video.

```js
$("#video1").mouseenter(function(){
  
  $(this).attr("src",$(this).attr("src") + "?autoplay=1");
});

$("#video1").mouseleave(function(){
  var src= $(this).attr("src");
  var arr_str = src.split("?");
  $(this).attr("src",arr_str[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="video1" width="200" height="169" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Inufy4FdnRk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
```

Comment: Garvit thank you for your answer, it worked but if you test it you will notice the video show up, then dissapears and then show up again with the autoplay function which is a bit annoying. I´ve tried to show the video using  .css("display", "block") in the .mouseenter method of your code instead but it dint work. Also, how do i offset the video from above the blue dot? I tried to apply a top style in the .css method but the video stays at the same place

Comment: See this link [http://jsbin.com/yocisupifo/edit?html,output](http://jsbin.com/yocisupifo/edit?html,output) . Here, I have used youtube frame api for displaying video and your css is not working because your syntax is wrong and updated that too.